# Neo4j apoc load json: No data in Neo4j

Tags: json, import, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am using exporting neo4j all db to json using apoc APIs & again importing with same. Import query executes successfully but cannot find any data in neo4j.

Export query:

```
CALL apoc.export.json.all('complete-db.json',{useTypes:true, storeNodeIds:false})
```

Import query:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('complete-db.json')
```

When I execute:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

It shows no results found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit confusing but `apoc.load.json` just `reads`(loads) data from the JSON File/URL.

It doesn't `import` the data or `create` the graph. You need to create the graph(nodes and/or relationships) using the `Cypher statements`.

In this case, you just read the file and didn't do anything with it so statement executed successfully. ***Your query isn't an import query, it's a JSON load query.***

**Refer the following example for import using `apoc.load.json`:**

```
CALL apoc.load.json('complete-db.json') YIELD value
UNWIND value.items AS item
CREATE (i:Item(name:item.name, id:item.id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Raj. I got it. I was thinking like graphml api. 

```CALL apoc.export.graphml.all('/tmp/complete-graph.graphml', {useTypes:true, storeNodeIds:false})
CALL apoc.import.graphml('complete-graph.graphml', {batchSize: 10000, storeNodeIds: false, readLabels:true})```

Answer (score 1):

[apoc.import.json](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.import/apoc.import.json/#usage-apoc.import.json) does what you need.

The export-import process:

Export:

```
CALL apoc.export.json.all('file:///complete-db.json', {useTypes:true, storeNodeIds:false})
```

Import:

```
CALL apoc.import.json("file:///complete-db.json")
```

([@rajendra-kadam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57037159/4996681) explains why your version does not work, and this is the complementary API call to `apoc.export.json.all` you were expecting. )